# Arduino + relays + multiple magnetic locks

Tags: arduino, relay

I'm new here.

I saw some examples on how to connect an Arduino to a relay to switch on a magnetic lock.

What if I have 30 magnetic locks. Does it mean that I need to have 30 relays as well? If I need 30 relays, will I have sufficient GPIO port on the Arduino connect the 30 relays? Any samples to refer to?

Comment: you could open 30 locks with one relay

Comment: yeah, but only simultaneously.

Comment: What if I would like to open a specific lock and not simultaneously?

Comment: Then you need 30 relays.

Comment: @Transistor 30 relays means i need 30 GPIO? How to do that with an arduino uno r3? I've seen demo with the most 8 relays.

Comment: Why was this down voted?

Comment: One relay === one control. Independent control of N circuits requires N independent relays. Trying to control all of the relays with one microcontroller might not scale well, especially since their locations are probably not all in one place. Any development board targeted for "IoT" (internet of things) would be better than Arduino for this application.

Comment: @MarkU I'm building a locker... it has 8 doors with electric locks initially. It will scale up to 30 and maybe 50 doors/locks. So it's near to each other. I couldn't find any tutorial with more than 8 relays, or how to use "IoT" board for this slightly large scale project

Comment: The sensible thing to do here would be to have an addressable module in each locker, a three-wire cable looping through all the lockers giving V+, GND and data. The module would power the solenoid using a transistor rather than a relay. You need to revise your specs and decide what way this is going to fail. If someone pulls the plug on your power supply will all the lockers unlock?

Comment: OK, you probably don't need an IoT network if all the relays and their wiring are inside a single "Amazon locker" array... but I'd still recommend using one microcontroller per column. That keeps the GPIO count low and the wiring harness manageable... (@Transistor beat me to it)

Comment: Also, since it wasn't obvious that each lock needs its own relay, another hazard is that relays kick back really hard whenever they are switched off (inductors oppose any change in current flow), so you need a reverse-biased diode connected across each relay coil. This "freewheeling" diode connection protects the driver against destructive over/under voltage. The physical loop area should be small, diode right next to the relay.

Comment: @Transistor guess I have to do more research on your suggestion. Not familiar with addressable module and how to link it up with the solenoid and transistor. Any additional help/pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks MarkU for the recommendation, I think I need to see if I can control multiple controllers using your suggested method since I only have a touch screen to control all the locks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending upon how simple the user interface is for your locker setup an Arduino may very well be able to manage a whole bunch of lockers. Yes you do need individual I/O control to manage each of the locks (whether that be by relay, transistor, FET ...) but there is an easy way to deal with getting the I/Os that you need for the Arduino.

The Arduino is capable of operating an I<sup>2</sup>C interface. You can utilize an 8-bit Port Expander chip that has an I<sup>2</sup>C interface. This can provide control for up to 8-locks. Then add up to three more of these I<sup>2</sup>C parts to control additional lockers up to 32 total. A suitable port expander part may be the PCA9538.

[image]

<sup>*(Image source from [NXP 9538 Data Sheet](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/302/PCA9538A-1127639.pdf))*</sup>

Each of the four port expanders in your system would have the A0 and A1 pins connected in combinations of 00, 01, 10 and 11.

Note that you can also find port expanders that have 16 I/Os if you want a different level of incremental build out for your system.

Answer (score 0):

If you use an Arduino Mega you'll have 54 digital I/O pins to use.  You can also use the analog pins as digital I/O as well.

This would likely be a simpler solution than using expanders.

Comment: You cannot judge what is a simpler solution on the face of just having 54 I/O pins on the MCU. It could end up being a cabling and wiring nightmare. Modularity can be a simplifier where an expander is placed on an interface board for each increment of say eight lockers.